# how to expose an simple web application on internet using minikube?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have VPS which has a public domain, now I installed Kubernetes with Docker driver, and I follow [this instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) to expose a simple service on the internet. but I am faced with a `Connection refused` error.

I attached a screenshot of my k8s status below:

[image]

I try to create an Ingress and load balancer service but no success full result.

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of kubectl get service command

Answer (score 2):

In order to expose and application you need 4 things.

- 1. **Deployment/Pod** which holds your application image
- 2. **Service** that exposes the port of your container
- 3. **Ingress** which holds the incoming network policy
- 4. **Ingress Controller** that manages ingresses

If you are using the katacoda environment on the official site, the step by step guide is correct and has no flaws. There may be hidden some more configuration if you are running minikube on a local machine.

Comment: can you provide more detailed sample , I am newbie in kubernetes and I searched a lot but could not find any practical sample